# How to edit an attribute while editing a feature?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, nodetool, forms

I have several polygons to edit / modify and I want to modify some fields in the attribute table at the same time.

I have the table open, but I do not see where the attributes of the polygon I'm editing are right away.

To do this I can:

1. Hit the "Select Feature" tool
2. Select the polygon
3. Go to the table and select "Move selection to top"
4. Re-select the "Node" tool.
5. Modify the polygon; one or several nodes, or maybe nothing.
6. If needed, go to the table again and change the necessary fields.
7. Pass to another polygon, and do it again.

Or I can use the "Identify feature" and "Auto open form".

With these ways, **I walk back and forth to the same tools**. It becomes **annoying** and **diverts attention** from the information I need to control ...!

The problem:

When I´m using the "Node tool" I can´t see the attribute that I´m modifyng or open a form.
To open a form I need use the "Identify feature" or the "Select feature" tools and got back to "Node tool".

I need to focus on the "Node tool".

Is there any way I can access a form that opens automatically while I use the "Node tool"?

Or is it possible the attribute table move to the top the line I'm modifying, when using the "Node tool"?

(QGIS 2.18.14)

Comment: I think you should open a feature request on https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues An indeed, a combination of either the identify tool and the node as option, or highlighting the selected feature in the attribute table would be nice.

Comment: I always thought double clicking on a selected feature to open nodes would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to select "show all features" and activate the "move selection to top" tool 
(replace your selection to the first position, the first line)

[image]

I think it gonna be better !

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently a way to do this (see suggested comment regarding putting in a feature request) but your workflow can be made slightly more efficient using a combination of 'show selected features view' in the attribute table and [QGIS keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html).

The show selected features view of the attribute table will just show you the features you've got selected in the map window - avoiding the need to click on 'move selection to top'. Assigning some keyboard shortcuts for select features and the node tool would at least allow you shift between them without the need for moving the mouse or clicking.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to easy editing of attribute values and I found a nice way to do it.
You need to have the `Identify results` panel ON. You can turn it on as in the picture.
[image]

You can click on the option `Auto open form` and the feature attribite windows will pop-up every time you select an element.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this configuration?

[image]

As you can see, I can read/edit the attributes during i'm moving the nodes. For more comfort, you can also change the display option below the table.

To open an attribute table in the dock you have to change the parameters like this :

**Menu settings > options >**
[image]

I hope I understood your query...

Comment: Thanks @keiko.

But "Show selected features" don´t work for this workflow.

If I move to another feature with the Node tool, the table does not show that feature because the previous one remains selected.